# Performance improvement, predicate system linq queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to redevelop a news system on a management asp net core app.
We can post an additionnal information about a user or a company, and these informations works with rights (a user is allowed to see or no with his function).

I'm using Entity Framework Core, and I've some problems with performance.. I'm student, my code is certainly horrible for you ^^

See that :

I tried to remove the ToList(), but it's throwing an error than there's another request by another thread... MY DbContext Lifetime is Transient

```
IQueryable<AdditionalInformation> query = _context
                    .AdditionalInformations
                    // Company is the company targeted by this information (can be null if it's an information about a user)
                    .Include(u => u.Company)
                    // SSTRNUser is the user targeted by this information (can be null if it's company additionnal information
                    .Include(u => u.SSTRNUser)
                    .Include(u => u.Creator)
                    .Include(u => u.Documents)
                    .ToList()
                    .AsQueryable<AdditionalInformation>();

                var user = _context.Users
                    .Include(u => u.Function)
                    .FirstOrDefault(u => u .UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                var all = new List<Predicate<AdditionalInformation>>();

                // These persons must have the vision only on the companies they work
                string[] specificFunctions = new string[] { "AS.ST","I.ST","PS.T","CONS.ALL" };

                if (specificFunctions.Contains(user.Function.Code))
                {
                    if(user.Function.Code == "AS.ST")
                    {

                        user = _context.Users
                        .Include(u => u.Function)
                        .Include(u => u.EntreprisesAsAst)
                        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                        // EntreprisesAsAst is the mapping table between the employee, the company and his planning on each companies he works
                        // For others Function, it's another tables
                        Predicate<AdditionalInformation> functionWorkerPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Company != null && c.Rights.Any(r => r == "AS.ST") && user.EntreprisesAsAst.Any(e => e.EntrepriseId == c.CompanyId));
                        all.Add(functionWorkerPredicate);
                    }
                    else if(user.Function.Code == "I.ST")
                    {

                        user = _context.Users
                        .Include(u => u.Function)
                        .Include(u => u.EntreprisesAsInf)
                        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                        Predicate<AdditionalInformation> functionWorkerPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Company != null && c.Rights.Any(r => r == "I.ST") && user.EntreprisesAsInf.Any(e => e.EntrepriseId == c.CompanyId));
                        all.Add(functionWorkerPredicate);
                    }
                    else if(user.Function.Code == "PS.T")
                    {

                        user = _context.Users
                        .Include(u => u.Function)
                        .Include(u => u.EntreprisesAsPsy)
                        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                        Predicate<AdditionalInformation> functionWorkerPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Company != null && c.Rights.Any(r => r == "PS.T") && user.EntreprisesAsPsy.Any(e=>e.EntrepriseId == c.CompanyId));
                        all.Add(functionWorkerPredicate);
                    }
                    else if(user.Function.Code == "CONS.ALL")
                    {

                        user = _context.Users
                        .Include(u => u.Function)
                        .Include(u => u.EntreprisesAsCon)
                        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                        Predicate<AdditionalInformation> functionWorkerPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Company != null && c.Rights.Any(r => r == "CONS.ALL") && user.EntreprisesAsCon.Any(e => e.EntrepriseId == c.CompanyId));
                        all.Add(functionWorkerPredicate);
                    }



                }
                // this function (ADH = 'adherent' <==> client in France)
                else if (user.Function.Code == "ADH")
                {
                    // He must see only the information about his company when the client is allowed to see their
                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> functionADHPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Company != null && c.CompanyId == user.CompanyId && c.Rights.Any(r => r == "ADH"));
                    all.Add(functionADHPredicate);
                }
                // Else there's other function (managers etc), and they're not scoped to a company (instead of specificFunctions)
                else
                {

                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> functionPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Company != null && c.Rights.Any(r => r == user.Function.Code));
                    all.Add(functionPredicate);
                }


                // There's also 4 groups like director group, administrative concil etc
                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "CODIR"))
                {
                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> CODIRPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Rights.Any(r => r == "CODIR"));
                    all.Add(CODIRPredicate);
                }

                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "COMEX"))
                {
                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> COMEXPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Rights.Any(r => r == "COMEX"));
                    all.Add(COMEXPredicate);
                }

                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "CSE"))
                {
                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> CSEPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Rights.Any(r => r == "CSE"));
                    all.Add(CSEPredicate);
                }

                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "CA"))
                {
                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> CSEPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Rights.Any(r => r == "CA"));
                    all.Add(CSEPredicate);
                }

                // On informations about users, we can check "Targeted person", and the person can see informations about him
                Predicate<AdditionalInformation> TargetPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.SSTRNUser != null && c.SSTRNUserId == user.Id && c.Rights.Any(r => r == "OWNER"));
                all.Add(TargetPredicate);

                // The creator of the information can read the informations he posts..
                Predicate<AdditionalInformation> OwnerPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Creator.Id == user.Id);
                all.Add(OwnerPredicate);

                // The director and the assistant can read all informations
                if (user.Function.Code == "DIR" || user.Function.Code == "AS.DIR")
                {
                    all.Clear();
                    Predicate<AdditionalInformation> ADMINPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.AdditionalInformationId != null);
                    all.Add(ADMINPredicate);
                }


                var items = query.Where(a => PredicateExtensions.OrAll(all)(a)).ToList();

                return Ok(new
                {
                    paging = new
                    {
                        pageNumber = pageNumber,
                        pageSize = pageSize,
                        totalItems = items.Count(),
                        pageCount = Math.Ceiling((double)items.Count / pageSize)
                    },
                    additionalInformations = _mapper.Map<List<DisplayAdditionalInformationViewModel>>(items.OrderByDescending(i => i.LastModificationDate).Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize))
                });





public static class PredicateExtensions
    {
        public static Predicate<T> Or<T>(this Predicate<T> p1, Predicate<T> p2)
        {
            return obj => p1(obj) || p2(obj);
        }

        public static Predicate<T> And<T>(this Predicate<T> p1, Predicate<T> p2)
        {
            return obj => p1(obj) && p2(obj);
        }
        public static Predicate<T> False<T>() { return obj => false; }
        public static Predicate<T> True<T>() { return obj => true; }

        public static Predicate<T> OrAll<T>(IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> conditions)
        {
            Predicate<T> result = PredicateExtensions.False<T>();
            foreach (Predicate<T> cond in conditions)
                result = result.Or<T>(cond);
            return result;
        }

        public static Predicate<T> AndAll<T>(IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> conditions)
        {
            Predicate<T> result = PredicateExtensions.True<T>();
            foreach (Predicate<T> cond in conditions)
                result = result.And<T>(cond);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

AddiInfo class:

```
public class AdditionalInformation{
...

        private static readonly char delimiter = '¤';

        private string _rights;
        [NotMapped]
        public string[] Rights {
            get {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_rights)) {
                    return new List<string>().ToArray();
                } else {
                    return _rights.Split(delimiter);
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _rights = string.Join($"{delimiter}", value);
            }
        }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: When facing performance issues the best would be to start with some profiling. Therer are multiple tools available such as JetBrains DotTrace (which is the one  I use). Spliting your methods into smaller chunks will also help analysis (because you can benchmark small chunks)

Comment: `throwing an error` What **specific** error?

Comment: Please show us how `_context` is declared and set.

Comment: Declaration of DbContext in Ctrl : 
        private SSTRNContext _context;

Declaration of DbContext in Startup.Cs :       
            services.AddDbContext<SSTRNContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);

Comment: The error : 
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.

The error throwing at the line of the first predicate is set (depending on context), and throw after execution of .OrAll() method

Comment: So create two context objects then.

Comment: So create two context objects then. --> I don't really understand, 2 contexts in my controller, and which one I use when ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things about this code (in no order):

- `.ToList().AsQueryable<AdditionalInformation>()` will never do what you would want to do which is run the query on the database. The `ToList()` will effectively load all the data into memory and everything then happens on that data in memory. That’s likely a source of performance problems here.
- Your `PredicateExtensions` work on actual function types not on expressions, so what you are constructing there cannot be executed on the database (meaning that it will always run in memory, which has the same effect as the `ToList()`).
- Instead of collecting predicates, collect predicate *expressions* and combine these as *expressions*.
- The `specificFunctions` array isn’t actually needed here since you compare against each individual item anyway.
- `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` will query the database *twice* per call, so if you want to compare against multiple roles, a better idea would be to load all roles once.
- The function codes `DIR` and `AS.DIR` clear all previously constructed predicates, throwing away all the work that has been done. So it’s a better idea to do that up front and short-circuit the logic.
- Instead of loading the user again, don’t load it at all but just reference it through navigation properties within your query. That way it can be executed there.

Comment: Sorry I'm noob but can u show me what's a Predicate expression ? Or show me an example of what should I do for a predicate (one of them).
Ok for specific functions, just trying to do a first sort, ok for roles (really stupid error..)
Ok for DIR and AS.DIR, noob also..
Ok for last, I was thinking that don't load all reference was better if it wasn't necessary...

Thank you very much

Comment: Check out [the lambda expressions guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). What you want is `Expression<Predicate<T>>`. When you have `Expression<T>` then that *can* run on the database. Everything else can’t.

Answer (score -1):

That seems you have `one open connection via DbContext`, but `IQueryable` will work async or will do async computations on your code, and after a while your computation takes much time to finish previous sql execution then it will block next/another sql execution on `IQueryable`, because you your query is conflicts 
 on `DbContext`, it is inevitable.

i assume you know differences between `IQueryable` and  `ICollection`

**My Suggestion**, Try to use `SQL Stored Procedure` to simplify your codes, in your code you are overloading too much on the hosting server. You can distribute between sql server and hosting server your computations.

Comment: Ok so I should do the same calculations on a SQL Stored Procedure and call it from EF Core ?

Comment: Yes you should, also it helps to use less memory and cpu on your hosting but it will consume more resource on your sql server but  you can split your query i.e. first query on SqlServer then get results with DbContext then do  secondary filter on hosting after that send result to user.